# Multiple Tabs and Sessions issue in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, tabs, cookiestore

I've an application which I am deploying as Facebook application also.

Problem is when I am logged as user1 on my app via Facebook, and try to login from other tab of same browser, session of user2 overrides session of user1.

Is there any possible way to stop session sharing in multiple tabs in rails2? Session storage is CookieStore.

Comment: It's fixed in rails 3 according to this [post](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/476). I think it can be useful for you.

Comment: no, that bug has nothing to do with this. You cannot be logged in as different users in the same web browser.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use two different browsers - one for each session - as per-tab authentication is not supported in any browser I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently IE8 has builtin support for this while for Firefox/Chrome you may be able to get a plugin. Checkout this post and see if any of the options are useful https://superuser.com/questions/264138/firefox-google-chrome-plugin-to-enable-multi-session-browsing